# Change style of Quick Search Box

Tags: android

I have implemented the Quick Search Box on my application and now, I would like to know if it's possible to change the style (the design) of this Quick Search Box ?

I really want to have the same design of the Quick Search Box on all versions of Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set a theme for the QuickSearchBox, to make sure it looks the same on every device. ;)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the Quick Search Box style with theme, but, what are the names of keys that I need to override for the Quick Search Box style ? I don't find it !